# Chartboost show interstitial on game over

Tags: android, ios, chartboost

When I want to show an interstitial on game over event for iOS I call this function:

```
[[Chartboost sharedChartboost] showInterstitial:CBLocationGameOver];
```

while for Android I call

```
this.cb.showInterstitial();
```

I now that `showInterstitial`method on Android can take a String argument, but don't know that to pass to mention that it is "game over" interstitial. Also on the site of Chartboost could not find the API documentation. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this can be solved with a Named Location.

You need to create a named location for "game over" as a user-specified string similar to this:

```
 // Custom location interstitial [[Chartboost sharedChartboost] showInterstitial:
@"game over"];
```

Our full documentation can be found here: 
https://help.chartboost.com/documentation/android/namedlocations

Be sure to check the documentation and trust it more than my example code. What I put up there is the general idea of what I think you need - but you want to be certain before you put it to use!

Comment: ...and you are always welcome to email our support team if you have any problems. I think this is what you need, but they can get directly involved if we need them!